# Injecting user within custom query in entity form field

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, filtering

I have a form with a entity field, where I use a custom query to retrieve the wanted entities. I would like to retrieve entities for a specific user.

My form field is the following :

```
->add('productService', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Type',
    'class' => 'EvoBackendBundle:ProductService',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->where('s.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $this->user);
    },
    'property' => 'name',
))
```

To use $this->user inside my form type, i inject it when instancing the InvoiceItemServiceType, like this :

```
$formInvoiceItemService = $this->createForm(new InvoiceItemServiceType($this->getUser()), $invoiceItemService);
```

And then using the form type constructor to set the property :

```
public function __construct(\Evo\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

But i get the following error :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Using $this when not in object context in [...]\Form\InvoiceItemServiceType.php line 36
```

Looks logic, $this->user is used withing a function, this can't work.
How can I filter the entities returned by my custom query fo a specific user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$user = $this->user;

$builder->add('productService', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Type',
    'class' => 'EvoBackendBundle:ProductService',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->where('s.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user);
    },
    'property' => 'name',
));
```

Read more at: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: your solution works like a charm. Do you have any idea why when I dump($this) inside this anonymous function, symfony throws me an exception (sounds pretty logic), but when my co-worker do the same, symfony dumps the InvoiceItemServiceType object ? we are working on the same SF version, with GIT, so we have precisely the same files. All cache are cleared. (i'm on windows with php 5.3.28, he's on UNIX with PHP 5.5.9).